# PHP Record Not Inserting into MySql Blog Categories Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have an addpost.php which has a form that submits a blog article into a mysql database.  The tables are:

**blog_post_cats**

```
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| postID | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| catID  | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**blog_posts_seo**

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| postID    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| postTitle | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postDesc  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postCont  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postDate  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**blog_cats**

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| catID    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| catTitle | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When a user submits the form, the post title, content, description gets posted to the blog_posts_seo table, but also the category selected passes the catID and postID to the blog_post_cats table.  Below is an example of the form fields.  Also how the category names and checkboxes get displayed from querying the blog_cats table:

```
<form action='' method='post'>

    <p><label>Title</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='postTitle' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postTitle'];}?>'></p>

    <p><label>Description</label><br />
    <textarea name='postDesc' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postDesc'];}?></textarea></p>

    <p><label>Content</label><br />
    <textarea name='postCont' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postCont'];}?></textarea></p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Categories</legend>

        <?php   

        $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle');
        while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){

            if(isset($_POST['catID'])){

                if(in_array($row2['catID'], $_POST['catID'])){
                   $checked="checked='checked' ";
                }else{
                   $checked = null;
                }
            }

            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
        }

        ?>

    </fieldset>

    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

</form>
```

So if the submit button is pressed, the insert statements get executed:

```
try {


                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts_seo (postTitle,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
                    ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
                    ':postCont' => $postCont,
                    ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ));
                $postID = $db->lastInsertId();

                //add categories
                if(is_array($catID)){
                    foreach($_POST['catID'] as $catID){
                        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_post_cats (postID,catID)VALUES(:postID,:catID)');
                        $stmt->execute(array(
                            ':postID' => $postID,
                            ':catID' => $catID
                        ));
                    }
                }

                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: index.php?action=added');
                exit;
```

What is actually happening is NOTHING is getting passed to the blog_post_cats table!!  So I am not sure what is going wrong?

I think the insert statement is correct for inserting the catID and postID to the blog_post_cats table, so I am suspecting there is a mistake with the following:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Categories</legend>

            <?php   

            $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle');
            while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){

                if(isset($_POST['catID'])){

                    if(in_array($row2['catID'], $_POST['catID'])){
                       $checked="checked='checked' ";
                    }else{
                       $checked = null;
                    }
                }

                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
            }

            ?>

        </fieldset>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, I figured out the problem why the catID and postID was not inserting ...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);
```

I did not include this code in my question, and I found that If I commented out:

```
/*$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

            //collect form data
            extract($_POST);*/
```

... the catID and postID was correctly inserting into the DB.

It seems that I was sending the value of the $_POST array to the stripslashes function, but it was preventing the data getting inserted into the database.